# Check same enum, C++

Tags: c++, struct, enums, integer, compare

I am abstracting my problem now but I am in this kind of situation.
Let's say I have 2 enums that are in the same namespace.

```
namespace some_namespace {
    enum class Something{
        S,
        O,
        M,
        E,
        T,
        H,
        I,
        N,
        G
    };

    enum class Else{
        E,
        L,
        S
    };
}
```

Now let's create 2 structs which have as a static field some value of these enums.

```
struct SomeStruct{
    static constexpr int enumValue = static_cast<int>(some_namespace::Something::T);
};

struct AnotherStruct {
    static constexpr int enumValue = static_cast<int>(some_namespace::Something::O);
};
```

How can I check whether the *enumValues* of this 2 structs are from the same `enum class` or not? I think I shall give some values to my enum fields and use some bitwise operator on enum values to distinguish? Can someone help? thanks)

Comment: You can't. C++ does not work this way. By the time you finished declaring them, they are just plain, nameless `int`s. Their original enum type has been stripped away, forever, and lost in the mysts of ether.

Comment: One wonders why you don't save them as their original enums?

Comment: I thought there is a way of assigning some integers values to the enum elements and then doing for example `auto same.= SomeStruct::enumValue & AnotherStruct::enumValue if(same == 1){//same enum} else {//not same enum}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simpler than I thought.

So I declare enum like this.

```
namespace some_namespace {
    enum class Something{
        S = 0,
        O = 2,
        M = 4,
        E = 6,
        T = 8,
        H = 10,
        I = 12,
        N = 14,
        G = 16
    };

    enum class Else{
        E = 1,
        L = 3,
        S = 5
    };
}
```

And then this leads me to check *whether two integer values have the same parity or not* . Thus

```
if((SomeStruct::enum_value + AnotherStruct::enum_value) % 2 == 0) {
    // Same enum
} else {
    // not same enum.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using just the static_casted `enumValue` it is not possible to distinguish the originating enum(as pointed out by @Sam). What you can instead do is introduce a new field that stores the underlying enum class type and leverage that to make the distinction.

```
enum class E1{ One, Two };
enum class E2{Three, Four };

struct SomeStruct{
    static constexpr int enumValue = static_cast<int>(E1::One);
    using UnderlyingT = E1;
};

struct AnotherStruct {
    static constexpr int enumValue = static_cast<int>(E2::Three);
    using UnderlyingT = E2;
};

static_assert(!std::is_same_v<SomeStruct::UnderlyingT, AnotherStruct::UnderlyingT>);
```

[Code Link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08b885399997b9cb)

Comment: Effectively you are just redefining the enum this way to be a struct - which seems pointless.

Answer (score 1):

As already indicated in the comments, you don't want to convert your enum to an `int` if you still want to know the type.

There might be some reasons to keep the type and the scoping while wanting to implicit conversion to the underlying type.

What you could do is to wrap the enum into a class that converts to both the underlying type AND the actual enum.

```
#include <type_traits>
template<typename TEnum>
class ImplicitEnumConverter final
{
public:
    TEnum e;
    using TUnderlyingType = std::underlying_type_t<TEnum>;

    constexpr ImplicitEnumConverter(TEnum e) : e{e} {}

    constexpr operator TUnderlyingType() const noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<TUnderlyingType>(e);
    }
    constexpr operator TEnum() const noexcept
    {
        return e;
    }
};

struct SomeStruct{
    static constexpr auto enumValue = ImplicitEnumConverter{some_namespace::Something::T};
};
```

[Code at compiler-explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/x58KG6)

This way, you are able to keep all the type-safe information where this is relevant AND you are able to convert it implicitly to an int.